# С чего начинать для рисования?

Tags: python, 3d

Надо создать программу в которой должно отображаться 3 фигуры со стереометрии (Куб, Пирамида, Сфера). Размеры - любые, условие чтобы они крутились. Кто может помогите мне кто чем может. Я не прошу выполнять за меня задание. Я бы хотел чтобы могли накидать наброски или ссылки с примером.

Доп. информация:
Язык: python sage;
Работал в языках: php, pascal, чуток с++;
Знание языка: Даже не вкурсе как его компилировать и где запускать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Простые геометрические фигуры достаточно просто рисовать и анимировать в [VPython](http://vpython.org/webdoc/visual/VisualIntro.html) (Python + 3D графика).
- Хорошие 2D и 3D графики рисуются в [PyX](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/index.html).
- Очень хорошие 2D и 3D графики рисуются в [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

Плюс есть еще очень много [графических библиотек](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting) на любой вкус. Проще всего начать, пожалуй, с какого-нибудь руководства по VPython.

Comment: можете написать мне ваш скайп или через что можно с Вами связатся. Есть пару вопросов

Answer (score 1):

А использовать 3д-редакторы не вариант ? 
Просто сейчас много open-source проектов и можно их использовать почти в любой сфере